# Target Vs. Targeted?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> - Do you know who the **target** audience are?
> - Do you know who the **targeted** audience are?

Which one is correct? Are they interchangeable?

Well, i mean: can we use the passive form of a verb to specify the audience instead of using the noun, and what a difference does it imply?

Answer (score 4):

*Target audience* is an established phrase.

*Targeted audience* is not usually used, possibly because it is the presentation or product which is targeted, not the audience.

The iWeb corpus has 53998 hits for "target audience", against 3511 for "targeted audience".

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "target audience" is significantly more common, but I have seen "targeted audience" used, mostly in a marketing context.  [This google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=target+audience%2C+targeted+audience+&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctarget%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btarget%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTARGET%20AUDIENCE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTarget%20Audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTarget%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctargeted%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btargeted%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTargeted%20Audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTargeted%20audience%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Ctarget%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btarget%20audience%3B%2Cc1%3B%3BTARGET%20AUDIENCE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTarget%20Audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTarget%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctargeted%20audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btargeted%20audience%3B%2Cc1%3B%3BTargeted%20Audience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTargeted%20audience%3B%2Cc0) confirms that "target audience"  occurs 10-20 times as often as "targeted audience" in the corpus used by the ngram viewer.

While US usage would favor "is" over "are" in this context, UK usage would not, and either is correct.